# Replace nested for loops over a set of integers with list of all possible pairings in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have the following:

```
for i1 in range(6):
    for i2 in range(6):
        for i3 in range(6):
            for i4 in range(6):
                # do stuff
```

I want to replace it with:

```
for i in possibilities:
    # do stuff
```

where

```
possibilities = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],...,[5,5,5,5]]
```

How can I construct this list for any number of nested loops? Is `itertools` the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `itertools.product` to achieve that

```
import itertools
r = range(6)
for i in itertools.product(r,r,r,r):
    print(i)
```

This will print

```
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 4)
(0, 0, 0, 5)
(0, 0, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 1)
...
(5, 5, 5, 4)
(5, 5, 5, 5)
```